# How to configure 'qsub' to use a scheduling system like LSF or SGE?

Tags: unix, task-scheduler

There are several scheduling system (workload management system). Like SGE(Sun Grid Engine), LSF, PBS. Usually on a workstation, using 'qsub' command can put a job in a queue, then the scheduling system will take over from there. I got some questions:

- Is 'qsub' a Unix command?
- How does qsub associate with a scheduling system? What does the system admin have to configure?
- Which scheduling system is more popular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
* Is 'qsub' a Unix command?

    qsub is the binary used to submit jobs in SUN GRID ENGINE. Just like bsub in LSF

* How does qsub associate with a scheduling system? What does the system admin have to configure?

    qsub associate 100% with the scheduling system. The system admin can configure from nothing "basic installation" to server resource, policies, esub, elims to define the rules on job launching. 

* Which scheduling system is more popular?

    Depends. When we tried SGE couple of years ago it had issues taking more than 10K jobs but now SGE improved a log. At that point we had to opt for Platform LSF, which is a paid scheduling system but works great for large clusters with good monitoring solutions.
```